# How to set values for a given index level in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am trying to set all values of a column in a multi-indexed pandas DataFrame, only specifying data for a single index level.
The solution I have come up with so far is insatisfactory, but this is probably best explained by code:

```
from pandas import MultiIndex, DataFrame
idx = MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3]],
                              names=['Cases', 'Time'])
parameters = DataFrame(index=idx)
parameters['CaseAndTimeInvariant'] = 1
parameters['CaseAndTimeVariant'] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
# Set the values in 'Time' for all cases to 1, 2, 3
parameters['CaseInvariantTimeVariant'] = 1, 2, 3
# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

The error is quite obvious, as I am not specifying anywhere for which  level the data is supposed to be. If I had e.g. another 'case', the length of the data would not suffice to determine what I mean with the last line of code above.

What I evidently need to do is to tell `parameters` that the data I am passing is for the 'Time' index level. However, all attempts I have found with `loc`-indexing either lead to:

- other DataFrames or Series with the full length or
- require the specification of individual scenarios

Currently I am doing the following:

```
for c in parameters.index.levels[0]:
    parameters.loc[(c, slice(None)), 'CaseInvariantTimeVariant'] = 1, 2, 3
```

resulting in:

[image]

While this does what I want it feels insatisfactory in two ways:

- it needs two rather cryptic lines to do something seemingly simple:
  (Set all values for `Time` using this iterable I'm giving you!)
- we're required to explicitly iterate over all index levels that are treated the same, so this does not generalize well to more than two levels

It seems like 'groupby' could be helpful here but until now I haven't been able to make much of the documentation.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, how can modulo arithmetic help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we always want to align the sequence with the most inner level, we could:

```
sequence = [1, 2, 3]
inner_level = parameters.index.get_level_values(len(parameters.index.levels) - 1)
n = inner_level.size // inner_level.nunique()

parameters['CaseInvariantTimeVariant'] = sequence * n
```

*Note that we still need to `sort` the index before assigning the sequence: `parameters.sort_index(inplace=True)`.

---

Below if we want to use the outer levels:

I would `sort_index` and then just repeat the sequence for `n` times where `n` is the length of the unique index (`Cases` in your data).

```
parameters.sort_index(inplace=True)

my_sequence = (1, 2, 3)

# below by level: parameters.index.get_level_values(0).nunique()
n = parameters.index.get_level_values('Cases').nunique()

parameters['CaseInvariantTimeVariant'] = my_sequence * n
```

If you want a function that always repeats a sequence by the most outer index:

```
def repeat_seq_by_outer_index(index, sequence):
    return sequence * index.get_level_values(0).nunique()

repeat_seq_by_outer_index(parameters.index, (1, 2, 3))
```

If you want a function that always repeats a sequence by the `nth` level in index:

```
def repeat_seq_by_nth_index(index, level, sequence):
    return sequence * index.get_level_values(level).nunique()

repeat_seq_by_nth_index(parameters.index, 0, (1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: This seems to me to have the same issue as the current solution that I need to refer to the 'Cases' level (and potentially all other non-'Time' levels) to do the job

Comment: I don't see the problem at all with having to reference a specific index or a specific level. I don't see how you could do this without doing that. Is pandas supposed to just know that your sequence references the most inner level in the multiindex or what? You can rewrite above as a function, either repeating your sequence by index level or by index label, so I tbh think it is very flexible. And it is actually quite fast as well.

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with an example of input and expected output where you show your concern, and where above method will have the issue you describe.

Comment: @mrclng, updated with a new example at the top. Maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: To be honest, not really... As I mentioned you can do what I am aiming for with a two-line for loop. Eventhough this is short the indexation is a bit too cryptic for my taste (especially because you need to adress the level that stays the same instead of the level for which you have data...) and I was hoping that there was a sort of builtin in pandas for what I try to achieve.

Although if there are no other solutions I suppose your answer does solve the general problem, so until there's a more concise form of doing this I suppose I'll mark yours as the accepted answer!

Comment: The most reluctant check mark I've ever received. I don't think "too cryptic" is a valid criticism when it comes to the indexation - creating an array that you assign to a `DataFrame` after having sorted the index is *common practice*. Maybe it is a bit cryptic to repeat a sequence based on the length of something else, but that seems pretty standard too. But yeah, there is no `df.repeat_for_every_inner_index([1,2,3])` in `pandas`.

Comment: There are two ways of looking at this really, as far as I can see: either you 1) assign your array to each block of index that you are interested in, or you 2) create an array that match the size of the entire index. You provided a method that uses 1, I provided an alternative using 2.